# proof $ \sum_{x\geq 1}\frac{-\cos(2x)}{x} $ is convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to proof that $ \sum_{x\geq 1}\frac{-\cos(2x)}{x} $ is convergence?

I guess I am suppose to use Dirichlet test but I am really struggling with it.

Comment: Hint: you're on the right track with the Dirichlet test. Show that $\sum \cos(2x)$ is bounded by using $\cos(x) = \frac{e^{-ix}+e^{ix}}{2}$.

Comment: Is the sum over *natural numbers* $x \ge 1$?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, it is.

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams So basically I need to show that there exists some $M$ which is upper bound of given sequence and therefore $\sum An*Bn$ converges? Also $An$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ and $Bn$ is $\sum cos(2x)$. But shouldn't be $\lim An = 0$ so I can use Dirichlet test? But $An$ is $zeta function$ where $s=1$ and this is divergence, right?

Comment: @Xoroxoxoxoxoso, $\lim \frac1x$ does go to zero. $\sum \frac1n = \zeta(1)$ which does not converge. The Dirichlet test does not require for the sum to converge, only for the limit to go to zero which is a weaker condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the generalized alternate test (Dirichlet test). Show that
$$\sum_{x=1}^n \cos(2x) = \dfrac{\sin(n) \cos(n+1)}{\sin(1)} \leq \dfrac1{\sin(1)}$$